# How to create different screen size layout for Portrait layout only so that it don't have effect when device is landscape

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create layout for height i.e `layout-h<N>dp` that work only for device which orientation is on Portrait mode. If device orientation is change to Landscape then i don't want effect of `layout-h<N>dp` screen size layout.
Please help me if this is possible in android.

Comment: create other folder with name as layout-land and add those layout which you want when device is in landscape mode. layout included in layout folder come in potrait mode by default

Comment: Do you have a code sample of what you have tried so far that isn't working?

Comment: I think i was too early to ask question, I don't knew before `layout-h<N>dp-land` or `layout-h<N>dp-port` is also available for android. This way it worked for me. Any way thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Place the layout in a folder named `layout-h<N>dp-port`, where `N` is the minimum screen height in dp to use this layout. See the configuration qualifier names on [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).